# Wake on demand not working with Apple TV 3 & iMac Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, appletv

I have an iMac (mid 2008) with Mountain Lion. I recently bought an Apple TV 3 and read that this can enable Wake on Demand via Bonjour sleep Proxy. I've followed the guide at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774 however I can't seem to get it to wake.

- System Information > Wifi = Wake on Wireless supported
- Energy saver > wake for network access = on
- Network > set service order = Wifi first
- Apple TV plugged in, sleeping
- When iMac is on it appears on network as normal

I'm trying to wake it via a 2013 Macbook Air - the commands I want to use are Connect to server & SSH. I've tried using an Airport express for the Wifi network instead of the usual generic wifi router supplied by telco but this doesn't help and shouldn't be necessary due to the Apple TV AFAIK?

I can't do AirPlay mirroring from the iMac to the ATV because the Mid 2008 iMac is not supported but this shouldn't affect things either.

Ideally I want to have the iMac plugged into generic router via ethernet (to get fastest dl speed) and not have to use the Airport express (because router already provides wifi).

Am I right in understanding that this has nothing to do with the router, ie if I turned it off, the Macbook Air, iMac and Apple TV all communicate wirelessly between themselves?

Comment: My ATV2 and ATV3 can make my mid-2010 Mac mini.  ATV's are wireless, Mini is wired.  I am using Airport Extreme Base Station, but this worked even with my older Linksys router.  I don't think your final question is true: you can't communicate wirelessly without a wireless network (I didn't think these devices supported ad-hoc wifi, but I could be wrong).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, as Apple say you need an ATV or an Airport I thought it might be filling the same role but I think you're right.